# Error #2044: Unhandled error:. text=Invalid samplerate

Tags: actionscript-3, shinemp3encoder

I'm trying to save microphone output into an mp3 file using ShineMP3Encoder. Everything works except that when I try to set sampling rate to 22K samples per second, I get an error.

```
var mic:Microphone = Microphone.getMicrophone(); 
mic.rate = 22; 


Error #2044: Unhandled error:. text=Invalid samplerate
```

Is there a list of allowable rates for ShineMP3Encoder?

Just in case, here's where I use ShineMP3Encoder:

```
mp3encoder = new ShineMP3Encoder(wavData);
mp3encoder.start();
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation or source code?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#rate

Comment: when in doubt, check out the documentation

Comment: That link is not relevant. It's about the Microphone class, not ShineMP3Encoder which throws the error. FYI, I've been reading the docs and googling this topic for a couple of days.

Comment: The only code you posted was about the `Microphone` class, so give us more to go by then.   how do create/populate `waveData`?  What code is on the line that is throwing the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the hard-coded values of allowable sample rates in main.c inside the ShineMP3Encoder source code:

```
static int find_samplerate_index(long freq)
{
    static long mpeg1[3] = {**44100, 48000, 32000**};
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
        if(freq==mpeg1[i]) return i;

    ERROR("Invalid samplerate");
    return -1;
}
```

Since the only value that equals one of the Microphone sample rates is 44100, other sample rates will cause the error.